# Erro ao receber dados do Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou com problemas no meu TCC, não estou conseguindo receber os dados vindos do `Firebase` e exibi-los em uma listview, ele apresenta erro, estou usando o `ValueEventListener` para tentar pegar os dados... a `listview` esta em um `fragment`. Alguem sabe como resolver esse problema ???

### ERRO:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: matheus.example.com.topaziovilleapp, PID: 13075
>                                                                                        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type
>   matheus.example.com.topaziovilleapp.Modelo.Noticias
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at
>   matheus.example.com.topaziovilleapp.Fragments.fragmentNoticias$1.onDataChange(fragmentNoticias.java:61)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)

### Fragment

```
public class fragmentNoticias extends Fragment {
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String> noticias;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
private String usuariologado;

public fragmentNoticias() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticias, container, false);

    noticias = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_noticias);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            noticias
    );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    autenticacao = FirebaseConfig.getAutenticacao();
    databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Noticias");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            noticias.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Noticias noticia = dados.getValue(Noticias.class);
                noticias.add(noticia.getTitulo());

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

### Classe Modelo

```
public class Noticias {
private String titulo;
private String noticia;
private String data;
private String imagem;

public Noticias() {
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getNoticia() {
    return noticia;
}

public void setNoticia(String noticia) {
    this.noticia = noticia;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getImagem() {
    return imagem;
}

public void setImagem(String imagem) {
    this.imagem = imagem;
}
```

### Imagemdo BD do Firebase

}[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu `onDataChange` já recebe um `DataSnapshot` como um *child-node*. Tu precisa apenas usar o `getValue` do `DataSnaphot` sem usar um looping:

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        noticias.clear();
        Noticias noticia = dados.getValue(Noticias.class);
        noticias.add(noticia.getTitulo());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que seu nó de "Noticias" não é um array. O que acontece é que você esta iterando sobre os valores do nó. Então

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        noticias.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            //Noticias noticia = dados.getValue(Noticias.class);
            //noticias.add(noticia.getTitulo());

           //dados.getValue() vai retornar: data, imagem, noticia, titulo como atributos.
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

O correto seria mudar a estrutura das Noticias.

ficando assim:

Noticias 
    - uid
        - data
        - imagem
        - noticia
        - titulo

Para isso acontecer, na criação da noticia, você precisa dar um "push()" na referencia.

Ex:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); 
map.put("data", data);
map.put("imagem", imagem);
map.put("noticia", noticia);
map.put("titulo", titulo);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Noticias").push().setValue(objetonoticia)
```